# Apply styling to VisualForce PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have created a page like below , when i run this , styles are not applied.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <style> body { font-family: Arial Unicode MS; font-size:72px;} </style>
    <h1>Congratulations</h1>
    <p>This is your new PDF</p>
</apex:page>
```

How to apply style in pdf salesforce ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm):

> If you use inline CSS styles, set the API version to 28.0 or later.
>   Also set `<apex:page applyBodyTag="false">`, and add static, valid
>   `<head> and <body>` tags to your page.